# Pagination in blog posts when query posts by postdata

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using the below codes to query post from `'post_type' => 'post'`
I can use pagination by `if/while` loop. Now I am using postdata query on a theme.
**Now how can I set pagination on it.**

My codes:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type'=> 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="title bg-colored">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf"></div>
<?php endforeach;               

wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Pagination page in Codex

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

There is all the necessary function calls for simple pagination.

Also look at this function

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your code to this :

global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type'=> 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $paged, );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="title bg-colored">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf"></div>
<?php endforeach;               

wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

Let me know if this works fine ;)

Cheers!